# When are range-based for loops better than regular for loops?

Tags: loops

Is it when you need faster performance, to iterate over a container, or when you don't need an index variable?

From my understanding it should be when you need to iterate over a container.

Am I understanding this properly?

Comment: What do you mean by a "range-based for loop" and a "regular for loop"?  What's the difference you have in mind?  Can you give a definition, an example, some context?  What makes you think one is better?  Did you read something somewhere that said that?

Comment: I think questions about coding style are offtopic here.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you don't need an index variable and don't need to iterate over the objects in a particular order, then range-based for loops can be easier to understand, and less verbose. Outside of those conditions, it's usually a matter of taste. You're basically saying, "for each object in the container, do this," as opposed to saying, "for each index in the container, retrieve the object at the index, and for each object you've retrieved, do this."

Answer (score 0):

I follow a simple rule: Use regular for loops only if you HAVE to. Use range based anytime you can as they make your code cleaner, more concise and less prone to error.